# Angular UI Grid autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I've added a custom editable cell template in ui-grid column
this is the code :

```
{ 
  name:'progetto',
  width: '42%',
  enableCellEditOnFocus: true,
  cellEditableCondition: true,
  cellTemplate:'<div style="text-align:left;height: 40px;line-height: 40px;font-size:1.1em;padding-left:10px;">{{COL_FIELD}}</div>',
  editableCellTemplate: '<ui-select-wrap><div class="typeaheadcontainer"><input type="INPUT_TYPE"  ng-model="MODEL_COL_FIELD"  class="typeaheadcontrol" style="color:#333;text-align:left;height:40px;line-height:40px;font-size:1.1em;padding-left:10px;"  ui-grid-editor uib-typeahead="name as progetto.name for progetto in grid.appScope.progetti | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8" typeahead-min-length="0" ng-required="true" typeahead-editable ="false" data-typeahead-on-select="grid.appScope.typeaheadSelected(row.entity, $item)" /></div></ui-select-wrap>',
  headerCellTemplate: $scope.headerTemplate,
  cellClass: 'grid-align'
}
```

But when i select the function `grid.appScope.typeaheadSelected(row.entity, $item)` is not invoked.
Any suggestion? Thank you!